# max and min of $f(x,y,z)=(x-1)e^x+y^2+z^2+2z$ subject to $x+y+z=1$

Tags: real-analysis

The set V=$\{(x,y,z)\in R^3:x+y+z=1\}$ is compact and f is continuous on V so for Weierstrass
global max and min exist. I found with Lagrange'multiplyers the point $(a,1-{a \over 2},-{a \over 2}),a\in (0,1)$ and studying hessian matrix is a global min.But for the global max?

Comment: What does that definition of $V$ *mean*?

Comment: Do you intend for $x$, $y$, $z$ to all be nonnegative?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos from the title I assume it's $\{(x, y, z) | x + y + z = 1\}$.

Comment: @hunter Maybe. But then it is **not** compact.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos good point. I'll bet the other comment is right and we intend the variables to be non-negative. I'll delete my answer.